# How to add site list to Java Security without using the UI?

Tags: java, security

There is an exception list on java security tab like the picture below.[image: java add site list]

I want to add websites to this list using the command line. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I will use it internally for testing and the VM will be deleted within one hour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/exception_site_list.html) tells us:

> The location of the exception site list is set in the
>   **deployment.user.security.exception.sites** property. The default
>   location is `<deployment.user.home>/security/exception.sites`.

So you could add URLs to that file pretty easily on the command line.

Comment: On my machine, this file was found at `C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment\exception.sites`

Comment: where is it now in version 8?

Answer (score 7):

Just checked, on Java 8.111 and Windows 7 Corporate it can be found at

c:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites

But I suppose that this file (as well as the whole directory chain) is not created by default. So may be you should first add it **by hand**, then **search** for the exact file location.

Answer (score 0):

You can create exception.sites file.And edit it as text file.Then you can place this file in

1. c:\Users%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
2. C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment\